# LibGDX Out of Memory at certrain Array size

Tags: arrays, memory, libgdx, out

i'm trying to make a 2D Minecraft clone with LibGdx i'd like to store my world in a 3d Integer Array where the `first[x]` is the `x-coordinate` in the world the `second[y]` is the `y- coourdinate` and the[z] coordinate gives the Region which the block is set on the Texturesheet(which "block" is set at this position)

My problem is it still works with those sizes `Array[25000][50][2]` but i get an Out of Memory exception as soon as i try it with `Array[30000][50][2]`.

Comment: You should not cache 3 million (30000 * 50 * 2) tiles at the same time. Only load small parts around your players.

Comment: i don't load them at once they are constantly generated when the player moves left or right and also they are not tiles they are just the map background i only have about 1500 sprites and they never get more they are updated by the data stored in the map array

Comment: map background is the wrong word they are just integers stored in an 3D array nothing more and they are only generated if the player comes close to them

Comment: It doesn'T matter if they are generated when the player is close or not, you allocate the memory completely, for the worst case.